# Extract a date from dataframe and plot time series with R

Tags: regex, r, datetime, ggplot2

I would like to plot a time series which presents the number of `log`s hourly. I tried at first to split the the `date` of every `log` from the `dataframe` in order to count the number of `log`s hourly.

I have the following `dataframe` :

```
[Fri Jun  1 15:56:37 1995] httpd: send aborted for disarray.demon.co.uk
[Fri Jun  1 16:29:29 1995] httpd: send aborted for ansc86024.usask.ca
[Fri Jun  1 16:31:42 1995] httpd: send aborted for 194.20.24.70
[Fri Jun  1 16:34:11 1995] httpd: send aborted for sw24-70.iol.it
[Fri Jun  1 16:41:02 1995] httpd: send aborted for educ026.usask.ca
[Fri Jun  1 16:41:13 1995] httpd: send aborted for educ026.usask.ca
[Fri Jun  1 16:41:13 1995] httpd: send aborted for sw24-70.iol.it
[Fri Jun  1 16:45:07 1995] httpd: send aborted for 128.233.18.38
[Fri Jun  1 17:26:50 1995] httpd: send aborted for pc117c.nwrel.org
[Fri Jun  1 17:46:53 1995] httpd: send aborted for geoff.usask.ca
[Fri Jun  2 17:57:09 1995] httpd: send aborted for piweba3y.prodigy.com
[Fri Jun  2 17:57:50 1995] httpd: send aborted for piweba3y.prodigy.com
[Fri Jun  2 18:10:15 1995] httpd: send aborted for 193.74.92.109
[Fri Jun  2 20:14:30 1995] httpd: send aborted for 128.233.13.41
[Fri Jun  2 20:15:59 1995] httpd: send aborted for peter.net4.io.org
[Fri Jun  2 21:11:54 1995] httpd: send aborted for ped374.usask.ca
```

I want to get the following plot with the number of `log`s hourly :

[image]

I tried to add the `date` column using the `gsub` function :

```
df$date <- gsub(".+[(.*)]","",df[0])
```

Comment: So you want to extract the date and then group by hour? Please show us the code you've tried already.

Comment: @eipi10 exactly I want to extract the date and group by hour, but I dont have a specific column for `date` I should extract date from the line and convert them to timestamp or other format

Comment: @eipi10 I tried to extract date using the following regex formula : `df$date <- gsub(".+[(.*)]","",df[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
# Data in form of a string vector
dat = c("[Fri Jun 1 15:56:37 1995] httpd: send aborted for disarray.demon.co.uk", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:29:29 1995] httpd: send aborted for ansc86024.usask.ca", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:31:42 1995] httpd: send aborted for 194.20.24.70", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:34:11 1995] httpd: send aborted for sw24-70.iol.it", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:41:02 1995] httpd: send aborted for educ026.usask.ca", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:41:13 1995] httpd: send aborted for educ026.usask.ca", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:41:13 1995] httpd: send aborted for sw24-70.iol.it", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 16:45:07 1995] httpd: send aborted for 128.233.18.38", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 17:26:50 1995] httpd: send aborted for pc117c.nwrel.org", 
        "[Fri Jun 1 17:46:53 1995] httpd: send aborted for geoff.usask.ca", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 17:57:09 1995] httpd: send aborted for piweba3y.prodigy.com", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 17:57:50 1995] httpd: send aborted for piweba3y.prodigy.com", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 18:10:15 1995] httpd: send aborted for 193.74.92.109", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 20:14:30 1995] httpd: send aborted for 128.233.13.41", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 20:15:59 1995] httpd: send aborted for peter.net4.io.org", 
        "[Fri Jun 2 21:11:54 1995] httpd: send aborted for ped374.usask.ca")

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

Extract date string:

```
dat = data.frame(date.string = gsub(".{5}(.*)\\].*", "\\1", dat))
```

Convert date string to POSIXct datetime format:

```
dat$date = as.POSIXct(dat$date.string, format= "%b %e %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Now, summarise by hour. We throw away the minutes and seconds so that we can then just group by date to get counts by hour:

```
datByHour = dat %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(paste0(paste(year(date),month(date),day(date),sep="-"), 
                                  " ", 
                                  paste(hour(date),"00:00", sep=":")))) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  tally 

datByHour
```

> ```
>                  date     n
> 1 1995-06-01 15:00:00     1
> 2 1995-06-01 16:00:00     7
> 3 1995-06-01 17:00:00     2
> 4 1995-06-02 17:00:00     2
> 5 1995-06-02 18:00:00     1
> 6 1995-06-02 20:00:00     2
> 7 1995-06-02 21:00:00     1
> ```

Plot hourly counts:

```
ggplot(datByHour, aes(date, n)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%b %e, %Y: %H")
```

Comment: I get the following error message : `> df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date.string, format= "%b %e %H:%M:%S %Y")
 Error in strptime(x, format, tz = tz) : 
  the input string is too long`

Comment: I've updated the code a bit from my original answer to simplify the regular expression and change the method of grouping by hour.

Comment: Yes, in my case I have a `dataframe` object ot a `string vector`